# (TS) Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a Functional Component defined using TS that I am passing in object on Props to give the component access to some actionCreators.   There are no actual Props values to pass in.  However, I am using the prop mechanism to pass in the a type to access the actionCreator methods.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { connect, useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { ApplicationState } from "../store";
import * as VerifyCheckStore from "../store/VerifyCheck";

type VerifyCheckProps = typeof VerifyCheckStore.actionCreators;

const VerifyCheckVerificationSuccess: React.FunctionComponent<VerifyCheckProps> = (props) => 
{
    const selectVerifyCheckState = (state: ApplicationState) => state.verifyCheck;
    const verifyCheckState: any = useSelector(selectVerifyCheckState);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const submitData = (processState: string) => {
    VerifyCheckStore.actionCreators.setProcessState(processState);
}

return <div>
    <div>Check has been verified as a valid AutoCheck</div>
    <div>Do you wish to adopt this Autocheck for the purpose of using the check to pay for a customer's vehicle?</div>
    <button className="btn btn-primary" name="btnAdopt" onClick={() => { submitData("adoptStart") }} >Adopt</button>
    <button className="btn btn-primary" name="btnAdopt" onClick={() => { submitData("start"); }} >Cancel</button>
</div>;
}        
VerifyCheckVerificationSuccess.defaultProps = {}
export default connect()(VerifyCheckVerificationSuccess);
```

When I go to use the FC i get the following TS error.

Error   TS2739  (TS) Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<{ setProcessState: (processState: string) => AppThunkAction; postdata: (checkNumber: string, verificationCode: string) => AppThunkAction; requestVerifyCheck: () => AppThunkAction<...>; }, "setProcessState" | ... 1 more ... | "requestVerifyCheck">': setProcessState, postdata, requestVerifyCheck

How can i pass in objects on the props mechanism without having to define the values when using the FC?

If this is not the correct way to get access to the actionCreator methods please let me know.   I am new to React and just learning.

Comment: I'm struggling a little to follow, maybe you could clarify something; if you aren't passing something in as props, how is it supposed to get into the component?

Comment: Thats actually what I am trying to figure out.   What is the best way to access the actionCreator methods inside a FC.  Maybe trying to add it to props is not the correct way to do it.   This pattern is based on the way actionCreators are passed into a component in Microsofts React Template app.  Just that they are deriving from Rect Class Component and not a React FC.

Comment: There are basically two ways to get anything into a component in react; via. props, or using context. Can you link the example you've looked at to give a bit of context?

Comment: You know what.   In the Class example the actionCreators are being passed into the class when exporting default connect.

Comment: I think what I need to do is create a wrapper FC that passing the actionCreator object and then call the wrapper FC w/o any props.   Sound right?

Comment: So I was able to get the TS error to go away by adding "as any" to the export default connect method.   

export default connect()(VerifyCheckVerificationSuccess as any);

Comment: normally `connect` takes at least one argument, though I'm not sure how you have things setup; it seems like `connect` is expecting `VerifyCheckVerificationSuccess` to have some props which it doesn't, but exactly how best to fix it depends on the context. The `as any` is basically saying forget what types this thing expects, so I'm guessing when you come to use the component that typescript won't be able to verify what props it should or shouldn't have

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the error to go away by adding "as any" to the export default connect.  I know this is a hack and not really using TS as it was intended but I got to move on.

```
export default connect()(VerifyCheckVerificationSuccess as any);
```